# What is the alternative to thunk dispatch in saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux-saga, redux-thunk

In my react project, I have the following code.

```
import uuid from 'uuid';
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from './types';

export const setAlert = (msg, alertType, timeout = 5000) => dispatch => {
  const id = uuid.v4();
  dispatch({
    type: SET_ALERT,
    payload: { msg, alertType, id }
  });

  setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: REMOVE_ALERT, payload: id }), timeout);
};
```

Here thunk has been used. Im applying saga into the project and I want to rewrite with saga. Since there is no API calls, i dont want to send through via a saga to the reducer. I want to go to the reducer from this action directly. So how can I rewrite without dispatch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sagas are to used to handle side-effects, You can use `put` to dispatch an action directly from your saga.

Here's an example from redux-saga official [docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/)

```
import { call, put, takeEvery, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import Api from '...'

// worker Saga: will be fired on USER_FETCH_REQUESTED actions
function* fetchUser(action) {
   try {
      const user = yield call(Api.fetchUser, action.payload.userId);
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_SUCCEEDED", user: user});
   } catch (e) {
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_FAILED", message: e.message});
   }
}
```

so If I am to write your code it will be something like this:

```
import uuid from 'uuid';
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from './types';
import { put } from 'redux-saga/effects'

export const setAlert = (msg, alertType, timeout = 5000) => {
  const id = uuid.v4();
  put({
    type: SET_ALERT,
    payload: { msg, alertType, id }
  });

  setTimeout(() => put({ type: REMOVE_ALERT, payload: id }), timeout);
};
```

In your worker saga:

```
function* someAction(action) {
  try {
     // some logic
     yield setAlert(msg, 5000);
  } catch (e) {
     // some error handling logic
  }
}
```

I have not tested it, however it should work.